# Redmine The entry or revision was not found in the repository.

Tags: git, redmine

I'm trying to add an existing git repo to redmine running locally on Windows 8. Redmine was installed with bitnami at C:\Redmine. I have a clone of the repo I need in C:\Redmine\gitrepo\Myrepo

I've created a project in redmine and can't seem to get the repository into the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to add a repository to a redmine project, you should follow steps below;

1. login redmine with a user has administrative privilleges.
2. Chose project
3. Chose settings tab in project
4. Chose Repositories sub tab in settings
5. Then Click new repository button, and location of your repository.

Answer (score 2):

If error still occurs, the solution maybe:
[Setting the path of the .git file exactly.](http://meandmark.com/blog/2012/01/accessing-local-git-repositories-in-redmine/)